# How to prove that the metric space $X$ given by the following metric is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be the metric space of all real sequences with finitely many non-zero terms  and the metric given by $d(x,y)=\sum |x_{j}-y_{j}|$. Prove that $X$ is not complete

Comment: Some intuition: what would a sequence in the completion look like? Presumably it would be an absolutely summable sequence. So if you take arbitrary finite truncations of an absolutely summable sequence, do you get a non-convergent Cauchy sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence of $X$ defined by

$$x_n(k)=
\begin{cases}
1/2^k & k \le n\\
0 & k>n
\end{cases}$$

$(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence that doesn’t converge in$X$.

Comment: Nice, I can show that it is a Cauchy sequence but for the non-convergence: I can see that if $n$ goes to $\infty$ then we obtain a sequence that is not in $X$, is it?

Comment: Right. And this is enough to conclude.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: @IreneGil You would really need to show that no sequence in the space can be the limit with respect to this metric, not just that your guess at a prospective limit fails to be in the space.  Hint to get started: show that each map $X \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x(k)$, is continuous which implies that if $x_n \to x$ in $X$, then $x_n(k) \to x(k)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $k$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I agree with what you say. But all is almost evident as $\vert x(k)-y(k) \vert \le d(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you, you both are right.